# HTA + vbscript file not getting loaded in window 10 machine

Tags: vbscript, windows-10, hta

I am facing an issue with hta file. In some machine it requires 3 to 5 clicks to get it loaded. Its not due to the slowness or computation in background. As soon as I double click the hta file It will get the user access control(since I am running in admin) to run on Microsoft(R) HTML Application Host. After selecting Yes nothing will happen. This has to do 3-4 times then only the file gets loaded.  The below code to elevate the admin right is causing  the issue. Thank you in advance for the support.

```
<script Language="VBScript"> 
HTAElevate()

Sub Main() 
    MsgBox "HTA-Ende", 4096 
End Sub 



Function HTAElevate() 

  Const Elev = " /elevated" 
  HTAElevate = True 
  If InStr( LCase( oHTA.commandLine ), Elev) > 0 then Exit Function 
  On Error Resume Next 
    window.resizeto 750, 10 ' : window.moveto screen.width / 2, screen.height / 2 
  On Error GoTo 0 
  'MsgBox oHTA.commandLine, , "5030 :: " 
  createobject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "mshta.exe", oHTA.commandLine & Elev, "", "runas", 1 
  HTAElevate = False 
  self.close 
End Function 
</script>
```

Comment: What is it you are expecting from us exactly?

Comment: HTA with the above vbscript requires 5 to 10 clicks to get loaded. If I'm removing the above code its working fine. But the hta has to be in admin mode due to some other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a race condition. You're trying to open the same file you already have open, hoping that your HTA will close in time before you open it again as admin. Instead, you should rely on a proxy application to start and wait for your HTA to close, after which it can reopen your HTA as admin. [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) is a great free option for this. Here's what I'd do:

```
// Get a handle on your HTA:APPLICATION tag - we'll need it to get your HTA's path
var HTA = document.getElementsByTagName('HTA:Application')[0];
// This object allows you to invoke a run method
var shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');

// Open a command prompt and ping your own machine once, just to stall.
// This buys your HTA some time to close. You can raise the ping count
// by setting -n <number> if you need to wait longer for some reason.
// Once that's done, it'll run nircmdc elevate and re-open your HTA as admin.
// The 2nd argument (0) means hide the command prompt. Set to 1 if you want to see it.
// The 3rd argument (false) means this is an asynchronous call.
shell.run('cmd /c ping localhost -n 1 & c:\\bin\\nircmdc elevate mshta ' + HTA.commandLine, 0, false);

// Close the HTA
window.close();
```